# PhpStorm take a step back in debugger

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

This question has been asked before for other IDE's, but what about for PHPStorm? Is there a way to take a step back while debugging?

Specifically after an exception is thrown, I'd like to easily take a step back. Or at least be able to see the call stack so I can quickly see where I need to set the breakpoint, because currently I just have to run again from the beginning and try to stop just before exception.

Comment: Question is: does PHP itself and its' debugger (be it xdebug or Zend Debugger) actually support such functionality (" a step back")? AFAIK -- no. **P.S.** Not 100% related (as this works a bit differently), but : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+Debugger#UsingthePhpStormDebugger-BreakingwhenThingsBreak-ExceptionBreakpoints

Comment: Look at my answer for some additional option for back stepping with a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can take a step back, sort of. The **Frames** window in the Debugger tab shows the execution path that was taken to get to this point. By default the debugger simply has the current frame selected.

You can easily click any of the frames, or use your arrow key to move up and down to view the state of variables and even the location in the code at that point.

Comment: I tried the way you told but i am unable to step back? I can see the frames is just a stack trace. Can you explain ? I often need to step back and have to re-execute the whole flow.

Comment: This is just to view the state at previous points in the stack trace. I don't think you can re-execute. But you don't necessarily need to re-execute, because you can step forward in the frames as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is something called `time travel debugging` that makes it possible to step backwards through the code. It records the execution of a php script so you can replay it and will be able to step in reverse mode.

One example that works with PhpStorm and Xdebug is this one: https://github.com/sidkshatriya/dontbug

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: 1st thing I should have mentioned is that you should be able to see where the exception was thrown in the stack trace displayed on screen or in a log file (see php error logging). You can then place a breakpoint a line or two above where the exception was thrown and run again.

Original answer:

You cannot ever "step back", but you can go up the stack. The entire stack is "current", part of the current state. But there is no way to step back in a program because programs can be fundmanetally irreversible by theorem.

As Gerard de Visser mentioned, it would certainly be possible to record every step of execution, in theory. But I think there's a much simpler solution.

What you *can* do is use the PhpStorm shortcut to "go to last cursor position" (VS Code also has such a shortcut, as I'm sure do all other IDEs). On Ubuntu, it's `shift`+`alt`+`left-arrow`, but on Windows I think it's `ctrl`+`alt`+`left-arrow`. I use this all the time when an exception is thrown. Then I put a breakpoint in and re-run the code.